# Error Android Studio: Emulator: EFER=0000000000000000

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando inicio mi emulador me sale este tipo de error. Después tengo que cerrar manualmente con el administrador de tareas tanto el emulador como la aplicación de Android Studio. Si reinicio 2 o 3 veces al final acaba por iniciarse la aplicación, pero la probabilidad de que salga este error es muy alta, y casi siempre sale la primera vez que inicio el emulador. Nada en mi proyecto da error, y el build me lo hace sin problemas. ¿Alguna idea de porqué da este error y/o de cómo solucionarlo?

(Editado)

Cuando reinicio varias veces el emulador se inicia, pero aun así en el Event Log me sale este error:

```
Emulator: OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library detected. Using GLESv2 only.
```

Comment: Dice que no tienes la liberia de OpenGL ES 1 ...

Comment: Ya, pero eso me lo dice siempre. El principal problema es el del error de EFER, que sólo me ha salido cuando ejecuto esta aplicación

Comment: Es por que donde usas el emulador, no es compatible con muchas cosas aun, si tienes la oportunidad de probarlo en un movil real, veremos que pasa